# How to add style customisation in Google Ads for React Native app?

Tags: react-native, admob, babeljs, googleads-mobile-unity

I am using below package currently. But I am failing to add style customisation in my `AdMobBanner` component. Please tell if any other package might be useful for Google Ads customisation or any other Platform Ads that supports customisation.

> https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-admob

[Please click on this link to see my current O/P. I want to remove border and add labels and buttons below it. Is it possible?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b42LN.png)

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
import { ScrollView, StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';
import { AdMobBanner } from 'react-native-admob';

const BannerExample = ({ style, title, children, ...props }) => (
    <View {...props} style={[styles.example, style]}>
        <View>{children}</View>
    </View>
);

const adUnitID = 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716';

export default class GoogleAdsCompo extends PureComponent {

    render() {
        return (
            <ScrollView>
                <BannerExample title="Smart Banner">
                    <AdMobBanner
                        adSize="mediumRectangle"
                        adUnitID={adUnitID}
                        ref={el => (this._smartBannerExample = el)}
                    />
                </BannerExample>
            </ScrollView>
        );
    }
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    example: {
        paddingVertical: 10,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    title: {
        margin: 10,
        fontSize: 20,
    },
});
```